# How many antisymmetrical relations are there on a set $B =\{ 1,2,3\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How many antisymmetrical relations are there on Set $B$ if Set $B = \{1,2,3\}$?

I believe its **three**?

Comment: What is your reasoning for thinking it is three?

Comment: Since pairs  (1,1), (2,2) and (3,3) are relations?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503979/how-to-find-the-number-of-anti-symmetric-relations

Answer (score 1):

It's not so simple. Lookup the definitions again.

The set $S = B \times B$ has $9$ elements.
So the subsets of $S$ are $2^9$.
Each such subset is a relation on $B$.

Try to calculate how many subsets of $S$ do not contain both
$(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ for any $a \neq b$. This is the count you are looking for.