# How many relations are anti-symmetric and symmetric?

Tags: relations

It is easy to show that number of symmetric relations on a set $S$, with $~|S|=n~$ is $2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ and (little bit tougher) that, number of anti-symmetric relations is $2^n3^{\binom{n}{2}}$( [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503979/how-to-find-the-number-of-anti-symmetric-relations) it was asked). But, how many relations are their which are both anti-symmetric and symmetric?

I have tried it, but no idea how to proceed. It's little bit confusing. I have searched for it in this site, this problem was not asked before. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Such a relation cannot contain $(a, b)$ with $a, b \in S$ and $a \neq b$. What remains?

Comment: Reflexive relation ?

Comment: Not necessarily so.

Comment: @metamorphy Is it then, No.of reflexive relations + no. of relx. relns excluding one element from S + . . . ? please correct me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relation on $S$ that is both symmetric and anti-symmetric is just a subset of $I_S = \{(s, s)\ :\ s \in S\}$. And any subset is a valid example. So the answer is $2^n$.